# sosreport shows no valid plugins were enabled

Tags: linux, yocto

In yocto enviroment.

git clone https://github.com/sosreport/sos.git

Follow the instruction and doing:

```
sudo python3 ./sosreport -a --config ./sos.conf
```

It shows:

```
root@genericx86-64:/home/sos# sudo python3 ./sosreport -a --config ./sos.conf

sosreport (version 3.9)

no valid plugins were enabled
no valid plugins were enabled
```

Comment: What do you mean in yocto environment? SDK? Yocto Build? Which Version?

Comment: I build yocto ( bitbake core-image-minimal ) to generate outupt image, use it to boot and login to yocto OS. Latest version, just git clone it.

Comment: can you post output with -vvv enabled?

Comment: and plugin list "sosreport -l", if no plugins where enabled you habe to enable at least one..

Comment: 'python3 ./sosreport -l --config ./sos.conf' shows no valid plugins found.

Comment: 'python3 ./sosreport -vvv --config ./sos.conf' shows set sysroot to '/' (default ) no valid plugins were enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Python 2.7 but I think the problem is the same.

Edit the following file:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sos/policies/redhat.py
```

and check the release string in the above policy. It should be the same as the release you have.

```
RHEL_RELEASE_STR = "Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for Python 2.7 but I think the problem is the same.

Edit the following file:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sos/policies/redhat.py
```

check:

```
_redhat_release = '/etc/redhat-release'
```

This file may be missing or incorrect.
you can replace this value with:

```
_redhat_release = '/etc/os-release'
```

it worked for me